# c++ How to return to a certain line of code?

Tags: c++

TL;DR - I'm looking for a way to return to a line of code after a `cin` statement.

I'm completely fresh to C++, not even a week into learning. I'm setting myself a little challenge to create a short proof of concept text-based adventure, with basic story and combat.

I've coded up to my first combat scenario, and I'm struggling. Here is my code:

```
int action;

cout << "Health:" << health << "Defence:" << defence << "\n";
cout<< "Actions: 1. Inspect. 2. Attack. 3. Defend";
cin >> action;
if (action == 1) {
    cout << "  Infront of you are 2 drunkars with knives. Not particularly wise, but fairly deadly.\n";
}
```

What I want to do, is if the player chooses Inspect (1), it will go back to these lines of code:

```
cout << "Health:" << health << "Defence:" << defence << "\n";
cout << "Actions: 1. Inspect. 2. Attack. 3. Defend";
cin >> action;
```

Right now, if the player chooses Inspect, it will tell them the information and then the code ends. I could, of course, just copy and paste the code after this segment, but that assumes the player won't choose Inspect again.

I thought I might be able to place in a `while` loop by creating an `int` called `Inspect`, where whenever the player chooses to inspect, the `int` of the same name increases by 1. But I didn't actually know how to make it so it would return to the top of the line of script, so it didn't really help.

Again, complete C++ noob, so I apologize for any stupidity.

Comment: Use infinite loop, `for (;;) { <your code here> }`. Use `break` to exit the loop, when the game should end.

Comment: @calligreat: Welcome to the community, glad you could solve it :)
About the downvotes: Loops are one the very first things any decent tutorial or book should have taught you. I'd wager a guess that people feel you'd rather work through one of those before starting on you own and running into a wall. Maybe give learncpp.com a try, if you haven't.

Comment: Hey nick! ty for the welcome. I'm using codecademy right now , and when I asked this question I had learnt some loops, but wasn't sure how to inmplement them in a way to get the outcome I was looking for in this instance.

Comment: This is a rather basic question, but I don't think this deserves 2 close votes and -9 score.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put your code into a loop, eg:

```
int action;

do
{
    cout << "Health:" << health << " Defense:" << defense << "\n";
    cout << "Actions: 1. Inspect. 2. Attack. 3. Defend. 4. Exit";
    cin >> action;
    switch (action) {
        case 1: {
            cout << "  Infront of you are 2 drunkards with knives. Not particularly wise, but fairly deadly.\n";
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            // attack something...
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            // defend from something...
            break;
        }
    }
}
while (action != 4);
```